# Error Loading Stream: Could not connect to server for RTMP stream

Tags: rtmp

I have a browser based application which displays an RTMP stream.
The RTMP stream url is similar to`rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935/oflaDemo/livestream.flv`

I can view the live stream from my home network. But from my office, I am unable to view the stream. I am getting the following error: `Error Loading Stream: Could not connect to server`.

[image: RTMP Error]

My office has a firewall running having only few specific ports open like 80, 443, 8443 etc.

My questions are

1) Is this a firewall issue ?

2) If yes, what ports should I ask them to open ?

3) How could I be sure that this is a port blocking issue ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, I think it's a firewall issue
2. RTMP uses the TCP port 1935

Here is the output with my environment:

```
Flash Plug-in Version: WIN 16,0,0,305

RTMP        DEFAULT     Success
RTMP        80          Success
RTMP        443         Failed
RTMP        1935        Success
RTMPT       DEFAULT     Success
RTMPT       80          Success
RTMPT       443         Failed
RTMPT       1935        Success
RTMPE       DEFAULT     Success
RTMPE       80          Success
RTMPE       443         Failed
RTMPE       1935        Success
```

It seems that port 443 doesn't work for me, I don't know why.

Comment: I had to open port 1935. Then it worked. Thats really useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**It might be.**

> *The RTMP protocol has multiple variations:*
>
> 1. The "plain" protocol which works on top of and uses TCP port number **1935** by default.
> 2. RTMPS which is RTMP over an TLS/SSL connection.
> 3. ...
>
> – [Wikipedia: Real Time Messaging Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol)